# How to choose where a macro should be executed (in a cell)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the following macro, that i would like to be executed in cell M153, right now it just list all the files in the A1 cell.

The macro should look inside a folder and return all of the document names in that folder.

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Here is the code:

```
Sub FilnamnRitningar()

Dim varDirectory As Variant
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim strDirectory As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim a As String
Dim o As String
Dim a1 As String
Dim a2 As String

a = Chr(228)
a1 = Chr(229)
o = Chr(246)
a2 = Chr(197)

Set ws = Sheets("Macron")
Set rng = ws.Range("A4:C100")

strDirectory = ("C:\Users\" & Application.VLookup("saljareKonto", rng, 3, False) & "\Dropbox (ATLE Consulting)\ATLE Consulting\Partner\" & Application.VLookup("partnerBolagsnamn", rng, 3, False) & "\Best" & a & "llare\"     & Application.VLookup("kundFulltNamn", rng, 3, False) & "\Ritningar\")
i = 1
flag = True
varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory, vbDirectory)

Range("M153").Select

While flag = True
If varDirectory = "" Then
    flag = False
Else
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = varDirectory
    'returns the next file or directory in the path
    varDirectory = Dir
    i = i + 1
End If

Wend
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,

Best regards
AgatonSaxx

Comment: Do you mean you want the output to **start** at M153, or you want all the names in one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, you want to list all files in M153 cell instead of A1? Then change this line

```
cells(i+1,i) = varDirectory
```

into

```
cells(152+i,"M") = varDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a batch script??

just do     `dir *.txt /b /s >> C:\temp\test.txt`

and then read into VBA!!